# How to Print with bluetooth printer in android

Tags: java, android

we are marking billing applicating, but i want to give direct print button, so users can print with bluetooth printer

how to do pls let me know

my code is

```
btnPdfopen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            templatePDF.openDocument();
            templatePDF.addMetaData(Constant.ORDER_RECEIPT, Constant.ORDER_RECEIPT, "test head");
            templatePDF.addTitle(shopName + "product list;

            
            templatePDF.addImage(bm);

            templatePDF.addRightParagraph(longText);

            templatePDF.closeDocument();
            templatePDF.viewPDF();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't you think that you need to get some sort of sdk for that bluetooth printer? And depend on that sdk send your pdf or any other documents?

Comment: yea,i m looking for how to implement and send data to print

Comment: You could find that sdk on their (printer's) site, I think